# more than one vertex group for one bone

Tags: armature, bones, vertex-groups, weight-painting

I'm asking if there is anyway in blender to make more than vertex groups assigned to only one bone? lets say I have a only one bone in cube and I want to assign four different groups representing the four corners of the cube. If anyone could please advise how to do that as from what I know that to link vertex groups with bones the names needs to be the same, but in my case there will be only one bone name and four different vertex groups names, so then how I'm gonna link those four vertex groups with this one bone if they have different names?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Could you just make one group which includes each corner?

Comment: I want this because I want to assign different vertices to different vertex groups, and these different vertex groups be weighted and connect to only one bone. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you know how to assign one vertex group to a bone? Then try that with a single vertex group where the group contains one corner and see what happens. Then try adding a second vertex group making the necessary assignments, and see what happens. This is a simple enough question that you should be able to the tests, and then come back and answer this question, sharing the results with the community.

Comment: @brasshat thanks for your reply. My question has been edited. from what I know that to link vertex groups with bones the names needs to be the same, but in my case there will be only one bone name and four different vertex groups names, so then how I'm gonna link those four vertex groups with this one bone if they have different names?

Comment: Well, I was already at the limit of my knowledge of animation, so I may be about to step off a cliff here. But could you create four empties linked to the bone so that they do what the bone does, and then link each of the four vertex groups to one of the four empties?

Comment: I don't want to link them to empty objects that follow the bone, I want to link the four of them to the bone, so that when the bone moves in pose mode, all the vertices in these four vertex groups follow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not assign more than one Vertex Group to one Bone. However you can assign many vertices to a vertex group where each vertex may have different weight. And that should be exactly the solution for which you are searching.

There is no benefit from splitting the weights for one single bone into different vertex groups. Even if that would be possible, blender had to merge the groups anyways before it could apply the weights to the vertices.

Please also check the wiki documentation about vertex groups:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/index.html

You should read all 4 chapters of that section.